# JQuery. Different keyboard events for same object

Tags: jquery

In few words, is it correct way to call keydown and keyup events, that included in each other, for same object?

For example:

```
$('#input_name').keyup(function() {
// some code here

   $('#input_name').keydown(function(e) {

   if(e.keyCode == 40) {
   // another code here};

   });
});
```

Comment: You're binding an *additional* `keydown` handler to the element each time to the `keyup` event fires. I get the feeling that isn't what you intended. Can you give an explanation on what you *want* to do?

Comment: Sure, it is autocomplete for search request. Keyup handler for ajax request, keydown is for arrow keys navigation through <li>'s in autosuggest. I'm new in JQuery and want to made it by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the code is valid, it is not a good idea to assign event handlers in this way, as you are re-assigning the `keydown` event every time `keypress` occurs. The only time you would really want to do that is when you are dynamically creating and destroying elements and you need to assign handlers to them - and even then event delegation is a better way to go.

Ideally you should keep event handlers separate:

```
$('#input_name').keyup(function() {
    // some code here
});

$('#input_name').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 40) {
        // another code here
    };
});
```

If you want to run the same function for multiple events you can do this:

```
function myFunc() {
    // your code
}

$("#input_name").keyup(myFunc).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        myFunc();
    };  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "included in each other"? Anyway, defining an event handler inside another is probably not what you want. Maybe you are looking for this?

```
$('#input_name').keyup(function() {
    // some code here
}).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 40) {
        // another code here};
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

Bind the events separately from each other, and then use a switch instead of if/thens. this will give you more flexibility in terms of checking for multiple values.

```
$('#input_name').keyup(function() {
   // some code here
});

$('#input_name').keydown(function(e) {
   var code = e.keyCode;
   switch(code) {
       case 40:
         //do something
         break;    
   };
});
```